# C++ object visibility

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What is the difference of

```
std::string a;
```

and

```
 std::string* a = new std::string();
```

if both objects are created as a result of a method call?
Are both objects "visibile" to the outside and when will they be destroyed or will they ever?

Thanks.

Comment: Visibility and lifetime are not bound together. A function `static` variable is not visible outside of the function but it outlives the function call, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you define these at function scope.

#### Storage Duration

```
std::string a;
```

This defines a variable called `a` with type `std::string`. It creates an object of type `std::string` with automatic storage duration, which means that it will be destroyed when the variable goes out of scope.

```
std::string* a = new std::string();
```

This defines a variable called `a` with type `std::string*` (a pointer to `std::string`). It creates an object of type `std::string*` with automatic storage duration, which means that it will be destroyed when the variable goes out of scope. That is, the *pointer* will be destroyed at the end of the scope.

This pointer is initialized with the *new-expression* `new std::string()`. This expression dynamically allocates a `std::string` object and returns a pointer to it. This object has dynamic storage duration and must be deleted manually with `delete a;`. This destroys the object that `a` points at.

#### Visibility

Visibility is a property of names, not of objects. In both of these cases, the declared name `a` is visible while it is in scope and not hidden.

Answer (score 4):

The *visibility* is the same, the *lifetime* is not.

The first `string` will be deleted as soon as `a` is out of scope.

The second `string` won't be deleted until you manually call `delete a;`

Comment: The "first" what? This can easily confuse a begginer. Both `a`s are destroyed automaticaly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they both are created in a method (function).

- The first one is destroyed as soon as the function returns.
- The second one lives as long as you don't call `delete` on it.

---

```
string* flunk() {
    std::string str;
    std::string* str_p = new std::string; // This lives on

    return str_p;
    // str->~();  destructed here. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both have the same visibility, which depends on where they are declared.

The first string is automatically disposed of at the end of the variable scope. The second is not deleted unless and until `delete` is called with the address stored in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string a;
```

will be destroyed at the end of the current scope (usually a closing } ).

```
std::string* a = new std::string();
```

will be destroy (deleted) when you call delete on it.

```
delete a;
```

as for visibility it depends where is it in your code; again, it will be visible in the current scope (delimited by braces) or if part of a class by the class access (public, protected or private).

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the first case:

`std::string a;`

A `std::string` object is created on the stack. It's then automatically destroyed when the object is out of scope.

In the second case:

`std::string* a = new std::string();`

`a` is a **pointer** to a `std::string` object on the heap, which is destroyed when you explicitly call `delete a`.

Regarding visibility, both are visible within the current scope.